# Producer/Consumer using multi-threading in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

Do I need to add any packages for the below code to execute successfully? I am getting errors in the code that I have been unable to fix, particularly with reference to using the `synchronized` keyword. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

Data object:

```
class Q
{
    int n;
    boolean valueset=false;

    synchronized int get()
    {
        if(!valueset)

            try
            {
                wait();
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Interrupted Exception Caught.");
            }


            System.out.println("Got:"+n);
            valueset=false;
            notify();
            return n;

    }

    synchronized void put(int n)
    {
        if(valueset)

            try
            {
                wait();
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Interrupted Exception Caught.");
            }

            this.n=n;
            valueset=true;
            System.out.println("Put:"+n);
            notify();

    }
}
```

Producer:

```
class Producer implements Runnable
{
    Q q;
    Producer(Q q)
    {
        this.q=q;
        new Thread(this,"Producer").start();
    }

        public void run()
        {
            int i=0;
            while(true)
            {
                q.put(i++);
            }
        }

}
```

Consumer:

```
class Consumer implements Runnable
{
    Q q;
    Consumer(Q q)
    {
        this.q=q;
        new Thread(this,"Consumer").start();
    }   

        public void run()
        {
            while(true)
            {
                q.get();
            }
        }

}
```

Extra class:

```
class PCfixed 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Q q=new Q();
        new Producer(q);
        new Consumer(q);

        System.out.println("Press Control-C to stop.");
    }
}
```

Comment: *I am getting errors*: which errors?

Comment: What errors are you getting?  Please edit your question to show exception text and the first couple lines of the stacktrace at least.

Comment: Don't you just want the `wait()` to be in the `if (valueset)`.  If the value has been consumed then the next put should set `n` right?  That shouldn't be in the `if()` block I don't think.  Same with `get()`.

Comment: No @mre, it doesn't have to be static.  He's using the same instance of `Q`.

Comment: Give your classes access modifier.

Comment: @JProgrammer All are public classes.

Comment: Are my threads going into deadlock situation?

Comment: Have you defined run method in Producer constructor?

Comment: @JProgrammer I changed the code just now.. Its working but I am facing a logical error... My code doesn't print anything on my output window.

Comment: Finally caught the error. :) The if brace condition is causing the problem.Wonder why?

Comment: So what was the problem? Is it working now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be impossible to answer correctly without more information, but the following is definetly an issue [though might not be what you are encountering]:

You are not calling `wait()` in a loop! The [javedocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28long%29) clearly indicates

> ...applications must guard against it by testing for the condition that
>   should have caused the thread to be awakened, and continuing to wait
>   if the condition is not satisfied. In other words, waits should always
>   occur in loops...

More info can be found in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038007/why-should-wait-always-be-called-inside-a-loop)

Comment: _Certainly_ _agreed_ in principle but since there is only one consumer I don't think this is an issue in this case.

Comment: For your amusement see the wrong accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960581/why-does-java-util-concurrent-arrayblockingqueue-use-while-loops-instead-of-i

Answer (score 0):

In both `Producer` and `Consumer`, you are trying to define a method `public void run()` *inside* the constructor. The curly braces are in the wrong place.

Comment: Yes.. the braces were at wrong place.But still I get a logical error during run-time.My program doesn't print any output.

Comment: If you run the program using your IDE's debugger, you should see what threads are running. Do both the consumer and producer threads appear? If one or both threads are waiting and never waking up, you should be able to see that too.