# Why doesn't thread wait for notify()?

Tags: java, concurrency, wait, notify

Why doesn't thread wait for `notify()`? The thread starts and then goes to the waiting pool, but it proceeds to execute after that moment.

```
public class JavaApplication2 {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
       ThreadB b = new ThreadB();
       synchronized(b) {
           b.start();
           try {
              System.out.println("1");
              b.wait();
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
          System.out.println("Total is: " + b.total);
       }
     }
 }
  class ThreadB extends Thread {   
    int total;
      @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized(this) {
            total += 1;
            //notify();
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: What notify?  I do not see any notify, except the one commented out.

Comment: Exactly, the thread must wait for eternity, but it doesn't.

Comment: try `b.join()` instead of `wait`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are synchronizing on the thread object itself, which is wrong usage. What happens is that the dying thread-of-execution always calls `notify` on its `Thread` object: `Thread.join` [relies on this](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Thread.java#1258). Therefore it is clear why you get the same behavior with and without your own `notify` in there.

Solution: use a separate object for thread coordination; this is the standard practice.

Comment: +1 for using separate thread for coordination. If you don't know what other parts of the system is doing with the object, then you can't rely on it for synchronisation.

Comment: You're correct, but not `notify`, the `this.notifyAll` method is invoked.

Comment: I don't understand this comment. `notify` is the same as `this.notify`.

Comment: `notifyAll` is not the same as `notify`. They are different methods.

Comment: It is not the same in general, but in your case (only one thread in the wait set), **it is**.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Great answer. So, why should use separate object? Even if we use separate object, that'll be part of the same tread of execution right?

Answer (score 2):

The method `notifyAll()` is invoked for the `Thread` object of the terminating thread. This fact is strangely documented in the description of the [`Thread.join`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join--), with the following sentence:

> As a thread terminates the this.notifyAll method is invoked. It is recommended that applications not use wait, notify, or notifyAll on Thread instances.

Thus, if you don't explicitly read the description of `join`, which you don't necessarily have to, you don't get to know the reason for the strange behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot depend on not returning from wait until a notify: "interrupts and spurious wakeups are possible". In general, you should wrap a wait call in a loop while the thread should go on waiting.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Yes, spurious wakeups are a marginal concern only and many implementations don't manifest them at all. Wherever you encounter deterministically reproducible behavior, you can be 100% sure spurious wakeups have nothing to do with it.

Comment: Completely agreed @Marko. I really dislike mentions of spurious wakeups.  They are certainly possible but extremely rare.  It is much more likely that try bugs are at fault.  See this wrong answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2960667/179850

Answer (score 1):

If you try your code synchronizing on any object other that `ThreadB` you will find it never terminates. This is because there is a hidden call to `notify`.

Although I am not aware of anywhere that this is specified, Thread notifies itself when it ends. This is implicit in the way the `join` method is implemented. This is the code for `join`:

```
public final synchronized void join(long millis)
throws InterruptedException {
    long base = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long now = 0;

    if (millis < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("timeout value is negative");
    }

    if (millis == 0) {
        while (isAlive()) {
            wait(0);
        }
    } else {
        while (isAlive()) {
            long delay = millis - now;
            if (delay <= 0) {
                break;
            }
            wait(delay);
            now = System.currentTimeMillis() - base;
        }
    }
}
```

(From the JDK7 source code)

As you can see, the calls to `wait` only make sense if somewhere there is a call to `notify` that is called after the thread ends. The same call to `notify` is what allows your program to terminate.

Answer (score 0):

You have nested synchronized {} constructs in the two places. These constructs seem doing something weird: the thread does not react into notify at all and only resumes when ThreadB (b) terminates. Remove this:

```
public class JavaApplication2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadB b = new ThreadB();
        b.start();
        try {
            System.out.println(" ### Waiting for notify");
            synchronized (b) {
                b.wait();
            }
            System.out.println(" ### Notified");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        System.out.println("### Total is: " + b.total);
    }
}

class ThreadB extends Thread {
    int total;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        total += 1;
        System.out.println(" *** Ready to notify in 5 secs");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        System.out.println(" *** Notification sent");
        synchronized (this) {
            notify();
        }
        System.out.println(" *** 5 sec post notification");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        System.out.println(" *** ThreadB exits");
    }
}
```

The code above probably works correctly: with notify() present the main thread resumes after 5 seconds and before we see the message that ThreadB terminates. With notify() commented out the main thread resumes after 10 seconds and **after** the message about the termination of the ThreadB because notify() is called anywhay from the other code. Marko Topolnik explains why and from where this "behind the scene" notify() call comes from.

Comment: You seem to be using the term "spurious wakeup" too loosely---it is a very specific concept and it is not involved in this question (or any other question on SO I have ever seen).

Comment: The main thread does resume when the thread b terminates, even if notify() is not called, tested.

Comment: Of course; `notify` is called anyway, as I explain in my answer. This is not a spurious wakeup.

Comment: It is also possible to look so ... I have changed that sentence in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing the same testing on the wait/notify opertaions while reading OCP SE 7, good catch. I think we should let the authoer to explain.