# Code with notify and notifyAll / synchronization (Help to understand)

Tags: java, multithreading, notify

I'm studying for an exam from a Book given by my professor and there is this code working with Threads and Synchronization: We want to be notified everytime the state changes (without missing a state change).

```
public class C {

    private int state = 0; // the state
    private boolean modified = false; // to show if the state was changed since actualization

    public synchronized void printNewState() {
        while (true) {
            if (!modified) {
                wait();
            }
            System.out.println(state);
            modified = false;
            notify();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void setValue(int v) {
        if (modified) {
            wait();
        }
        state = v;
        notify();
        modified = true;
        System.out.println("value set");
    }
}
```

And then it's writen:
**However, it is not guaranteed that notify() in the method SetValue(int) wakes up the printNewState Thread!** In Java we solve this problem
with the help of notifyAll() and take a little busy waiting:

```
public synchronized void printNewState() {
    while (true) {
        while (!modified) {
            wait();
        }
        System.out.println(state);
        modified = false;
        **notify();** \\(?)
    }
}

public synchronized void setValue(int v) {
    while (modified) {
        wait();
    }
    state = v;
    notifyAll();
    modified = true;
    System.out.println("value set");
}
```

I don't understand why the **notify** wasn't also changed to notifyAll()? It might not be guaranteed that this notify goes to a Thread of setValue(int) ???

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `notify()` method wakes up a single waiting thread, whereas the `notifyAll()` method wakes up all the waiting threads. The problem is that with `notify()`, the thread that is woken up is effectively random.

If some other thread is accidentally or maliciously `wait()`ing on the same object, it could receive the notification instead of the thread you expect to wake up.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14924665/845567) for some more information. The comments on that answer are also quite interesting.

**EDIT**

In the code sample you posted, the first `notify()` within `printNewState()` can handle only one update at a time, so it doesn't make sense to notify *all* waiting threads to post their updates. The code assumes, however, that only threads invoking `setValue(int)` are waiting.

Since `public synchronized void setValue(int)` is essentially the same as having `synchronized(this)` as the first line of the method, that isn't actually guaranteed. Any code that has a reference to an instance of `C` class can wait on it and screw up the code.

The synchronization and wait/notify actions should happen on an object lock/monitor. `private final Object monitor = new Object()`, `synchronized(this.monitor)`, `this.monitor.wait()`, `this.monitor.notifyAll()`, etc.

I would also like to note that `modified = true` needs to be placed before `notifyAll()` in `setValue(int)`, otherwise other waiting update threads will proceed without `printNewState()` noticing the update.

Also, `private boolean modified` should really be `private volatile boolean modified`, and the same for `private int state`, though an AtomicInteger may be a better option.

Comment: hey Grexis, i edited the question, sorry about that. I'm interested in your answer tho.

Comment: @ovoxo, see my edit. tl;dr the `notify()` instead of `notifyAll()` makes sense as long as you're sure only updating threads are waiting.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, it helped a lot :)