# Multi-threaded programming - Producer Consumer

Tags: multithreading

The pseudocode for a 'Inadequate implementation' of a producer consumer problem mentioned in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) is as below. This solution is said to have a race condition which could cause deadlock.

My question is : Wouldn't just modifying the conditions  of wakeing up the other thread as below solve the possible deadlock issue. That way there is not just one wakeup which could be lost, but subsequent multiple ones, or am I missing something. Trying to understand here.

```
int itemCount = 0;

procedure producer() {
    while (true) {
        item = produceItem();

        if (itemCount == BUFFER_SIZE) {
            sleep();
        }

        putItemIntoBuffer(item);
        itemCount = itemCount + 1;

        //if (itemCount == 1) <<<<<<<< change this to below condition
        if(itemCount > 0)
        {
            wakeup(consumer);
        }
    }
}

procedure consumer() {
    while (true) {

        if (itemCount == 0) {
            sleep();
        }

        item = removeItemFromBuffer();
        itemCount = itemCount - 1;

        //if (itemCount == BUFFER_SIZE - 1) <<<<<<< Change this to below
        if(itermCount < BUFFER_SIZE)
        {
            wakeup(producer);
        }

        consumeItem(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Wouldn't just modifying the conditions of wakeing up the other thread as below solve the possible deadlock issue.

No, the race condition still exists.  The problem is that there are multiple threads doing the consuming and/or producing.  When a consumer (for example) is awoken and told that there are items to be processed, it might go remove the item but some other thread (or threads) has gotten there before it.

The solution is to do the following:

```
lock() {
   while (itemCount == 0) {
       sleep();
   }

   item = removeItemFromBuffer();
   itemCount = itemCount - 1;
}
```

So even if the consumer is awoken, it immediately checks *again* that the `itemCount` is not  0 with a `while` loop.  Even though the `itemCount`  was incremented, another thread might have removed that element and decremented `itemCount` *before* the thread that got the signal had a chance to act.  That is the race.

It is the same for the producer side although the race is to stop the producer from over-filling the buffer.  A producer may be awoken because there is space available but by the time it goes to put items into buffer, other threads have beaten it and re-filled the buffer.  It has to test again to make sure after it was awoken that there is space.

I go into line by line detail about this race on this page from my website entitled [Producer Consumer Thread Race Conditions](http://256stuff.com/gray/docs/misc/producer_consumer_race_conditions/).  There also is a little test program there that demonstrates the issue.

The important point to realize is that in most locking implementations, there is a queue of threads waiting to gain access to a lock.  When a signal is sent to a thread, it first has to *reacquire* the lock, *before* it can continue.  When a thread is signaled it then goes to the *end* of the BLOCK queue.  If there are additional threads that are waiting for the lock but *not* waiting, they will run ahead of the awoken thread and steal the items.

This is very similar to this question about `while` loops in similar code.  Unfortunately the accepted answer does not address this race condition.   Please consider upvoting [my answer to a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960581/why-does-java-util-concurrent-arrayblockingqueue-use-while-loops-instead-of-i#2960811).  Spurious wakeups *are* an issue but the real problem here is the race condition wikipedia is talking about.

Comment: Also all lines that modify `itemCount` need to be atomic or locked.

Comment: Just fixed that @Adam.  Thanks.

Comment: In multiple consumer-producer case shouldn't the wakeup be sent to all threads? That way it might be possible to avoid the race?

Comment: No @goldenmean.  The race would still exist and would be made even worse because multiple threads would be awoken.  `notifyAll()` is rarely the proper thing to do unless you really do way all of the threads to wake up.  In this case there is one element to be processed -- why wake them all up?

Comment: Not sure how I feel about that last paragraph. I asked a question about it on Meta (without linking to your answer) in case you want to weigh in on it http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200185/148672