# Notify seems to be waking up more than one thread

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I am doing a sample program with `wait()` and `notify()`, but when `notify()` is called, more than one thread is wakes up instead of one.

The code is:

```
public class MyQueue<T> {

    Object[] entryArr;
    private volatile int addIndex;

    private volatile int pending = -1;
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    private volatile long notifiedThreadId;
    private int capacity;

    public MyQueue(int capacity) {
        entryArr = new Object[capacity];
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    public void add(T t) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (pending >= 0) {
                try {
                    pending++;
                    lock.wait();
                    System.out.println(notifiedThreadId + ":" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (pending == -1) {
                pending++;
            }
        }

        if (addIndex == capacity) { // its ok to replace existing value
            addIndex = 0;
        }

        try {
            entryArr[addIndex] = t;
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("ARRAYException:" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + ":" + pending + ":" + addIndex);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        addIndex++;

        synchronized (lock) {
            if (pending > 0) {
                pending--;
                notifiedThreadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
                lock.notify();
            } else if (pending == 0) {
                pending--;
            }
        }
    }

}

public class TestMyQueue {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final MyQueue<String> queue = new MyQueue<>(2);

        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
                        queue.add(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":" + i);
                    }
                }
            };
            Thread t = new Thread(r);
            t.start();
        }
    }

}
```

After some time, I see two threads being wake up by single thread.  The output looks like:

```
91:114
114:124
124:198
198:106
106:202
202:121
121:40
40:42
42:83
83:81
81:17
17:189
189:73
73:66
66:95
95:199
199:68
68:201
201:70
70:110
110:204
204:171
171:87
87:64
64:205
205:115
```

Here I see 115 thread notified two threads, and 84 thread notified two threads; because of this we are seeing the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
115:84

115:111

84:203

84:200

ARRAYException:200:199:3

ARRAYException:203:199:3
```

What is the issue in the program?

Comment: It seems you missed the actual purpose of `synchronized`. It’s to guard the access to the shared resource, not for performing wait and notify while accessing the shared resource entirely unprotected. Further, you should read the documentation of [`Object.wait()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--) really carefully, especially the “*…spurious wakeups are possible, and this method should always be used in a loop*” part.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I know we can use concurrent Lock.  but My task is to make a lock using wait() and notify(). So at any point of time only one thread should execute the code between the synchronized block.

Comment: Where in my comment did I say anything about “concurrent Lock”? The `synchronized` block *must span the entire operation*, including every access to the shared data structure, not just the parts where you perform `wait` or `notify`. You are accessing the `entryArr` and `addIndex` outside of `synchronized` blocks and declaring `addIndex` as `volatile` doesn’t help as it doesn’t make updates atomic.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the issue in the program?

You have a couple of problems with your code that may be causing this behavior.  First, as @Holder commented on, there are a lot of code segments that can be run by multiple threads simultaneously that should be protected using `synchronized` blocks.

For example:

```
if (addIndex == capacity) {
    addIndex = 0;
}
```

If multiple threads run this then multiple threads might see `addIndex == capacity` and multiple would be overwriting the 0th index.  Another example is:

```
addIndex++;
```

This is a classic race condition if 2 threads try to execute this statement at the same time.  If `addIndex` was 0 beforehand, after the 2 threads execute this statement, the value of `addIndex` might be 1 or 2 depending on the race conditions.

Any statements that could be executed at the same time by multiple threads have to be properly locked within a `synchronized` block or otherwise protected.  Even though you have `volatile` fields, there can still be race conditions because there are multiple operations being executed.

Also, a classic mistake is to use `if` statements when checking for over or under flows on your array.  They should be `while` statements to make sure you don't have the class consumer producer race conditions.  See [my docs here](http://256stuff.com/gray/docs/misc/producer_consumer_race_conditions/) or take a look at the associated SO question: [Why does java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue use 'while' loops instead of 'if' around calls to await()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960581/why-does-java-util-concurrent-arrayblockingqueue-use-while-loops-instead-of-i#2960811)