# Is there a good way to distinguish spurious wake up and Thread.interrupt()?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, interrupt, spurious-wakeup

I want to make a thread which can be interrupted at any time while be guarded against spurious wake ups.
The problem here is that both spurious wakes as well as interrupts work the same: they throw `InterruptedException`

```
void anyMethodCalledByThread() {
  // .. a lot of work before
  while (wakingUpCondition) {
     try {
       lock.wait()
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       // is it spurious wake up and I should just ignore it?
       // or is it actual interrupt and I should do:
       // Thread.interrupt();
       // return;
       // and check interruption status in methods above to abort all tasks?
     }
  }
  // .. a lot of work after
}
```

From that I see, there is no way to distinguish them with just jdk, even `Condition` is of [no use](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk12u/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.java#L197). Only possible solution I see is to use some extra `volatile boolean` per thread, but this makes `Thread.interrupt()` essentially useless by itself.

Comment: are you sure that spurious wake ups throw the exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> spurious wakes as well as interrupts work the same: they throw InterruptedException

That's not my understanding.  [Spurious wakeups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup) happen because a condition is awoken without being specifically signaled and has nothing to do with `InterruptedException`. Certain thread systems awaken *all* conditions when *any* condition is signaled due to implementation details.  Spurious wakeups is one reason why we need a `while` loop by definition.

If the `wait()` method throws `InterruptedException` then it was truly interrupted.

```
// we use while loop because lock.wait() might return because of spurious wakeup
while (wakingUpCondition) {
   try {
      lock.wait()
   } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
      // if the wait was interrupted then we should re-interrupt and maybe quit
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      // handle the interrupt by maybe quitting the thread?
      return;
   }
}
```

As an aside, I contend that we use `while` loops less for spurious wakeup conditions (which are somewhat rare) and more for [thread race conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2960811/179850).